# I want to create a Docker image which contains Java and PostgreSQL. I just want to create an Image to reuse it from anywhere

Tags: docker

I want to create a Docker image which contains Java and PostgreSQL. I just want to create an Image to reuse it from anywhere.

From reading the documentation I don't understand how I can do that.

This is what I tried:

```
user@host:/$ docker run -i -t debian /bin/bash 
root@container:/$ apt-get install postgresql-9.3
user@host:/$ docker ps 
user@host:/$ docker commit <CID> username/postgresql
```

Comment: And what was the problem? Did your image not contain postgresql-9.3? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel ? If you look at the registry, it already exists, see
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/alinous/docker-java-postgresql/
Another way, you can also add PostgreSQL to a Java container, like this one
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dockerfile/java/ or add Java to a PostgreSQL container...

so start your Dockerfile with `from dockerfile/java`

Comment: Means every time i have to work then I have to download the same.Is it possible to create a local repository with required configuration & share it among team?

Comment: Yes, see this blog article http://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

Comment: Add if you download a second time any package when you build a container, it will be almost instant if you use https://docs.docker.com/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

Comment: docker caches the image itself.  once you download an image the first time each subsequent time you run it (on that docker engine) uses the cached image. right?